# UIButtons as checkboxes in tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I am new to Objective-C and Xcode so please bear with me.

I have tried to solve this problem for many days now and restraining myself from post. The number of posts I have read regarding UIButtons with Tableviews is a lot and I think I am too dumb to understand why this does not work.

I want to implement a tableview with multiple columns of checkboxes:

> 1  item1  checkbox    checkbox
>   2  item2  checkbox    checkbox

Keep in mind that I am currently trying to implement only 1 column of checkboxes.

I am using coded UIButton and setting their image to one of my images: checkedImage.png, unCheckedImage.png

One string NSArray @"" (with item title) and one NSMutableArray BOOL (value for if checked) for every item.

**Problem:**
A checked button @index 1-4 will lose its checked image upon scrolling the table view.  Index 5 seems to stay put, others not so much.

When debugging the method: `-(void)checkboxSelected:(id)sender` seems to drag out the right @row(index) and the bool variable seems to be correct but image not.

My thought was that the UIButton changes state, so I implemented the buttonimage on all ControlState, no difference occurred.

Code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

#define sectionCount  1
#define itemSection  0

@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSArray *items;
    NSMutableArray *itemsChecked;

    UITableView *_tableView;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    items = @[@"1", @"2",@"3", @"4",@"5", @"6",@"7", @"8",@"9", @"10",@"11",     @"12",@"13", @"14"];
    itemsChecked = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
    {
        [itemsChecked addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:false]];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    _tableView = tableView;
    return sectionCount;
}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:    (NSInteger)section
{

    switch(section)
    {
        case itemSection:
        {
            return [items count];
        }

        default:
            return 0;

    }
}

-(NSString *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    switch (section)
    {
        case itemSection:
            return @"Items";
        default:
            return @"woot";
    }
}

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"itemCell"];



switch(indexPath.section)
{
    case itemSection:
        cell.textLabel.text = items[indexPath.row];
        break;
    default:
        cell.textLabel.text=@"Unknown";
}


static NSInteger checkboxTag = 123;
NSInteger x,y;x = 100; y = 10;

UIButton *checkbox = (UIButton *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:checkboxTag];



if (!checkbox)
{
    checkbox = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRectMake(x,y,20,20))];
                checkbox.tag = checkboxTag;
                [cell.contentView addSubview:checkbox];
}

[checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"notSelectedButton.png"]   forState:UIControlStateNormal];

checkbox.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = YES;
[checkbox addTarget:self action:@selector(checkboxSelected:)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    return cell;
}

-(NSIndexPath *) GetCellFromTableView: (UITableView *)tableView Sender:(id)sender
{
    CGPoint position = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:position];
    return indexPath;//[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}

-(void)checkboxSelected:(id)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *ip = [self GetCellFromTableView:_tableView Sender:sender];


    NSInteger row = ip.row;
    bool checked  = [[itemsChecked objectAtIndex:row] boolValue];

    if (checked)
    {
        [(UIButton *)sender setSelected:false];
        itemsChecked[row] = @NO;
        checked = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        [(UIButton *)sender setSelected:true];
        itemsChecked[row] = @YES;
        checked = YES;
    }

    UIButton* checkbox = sender;

    if (checked)
    {
        [checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkedButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkedButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
        [checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkedButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateApplication];
        [checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkedButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkedButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateReserved];
        [checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkedButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    }
    else
    {
        //[checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"notSelectedButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

}
@end
```

Header

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource>

- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;

- (NSString *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;

- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

-(UITableViewCell *) GetCellFromTableView: (UITableView *)tableView Sender:(id)sender;

-(void)checkboxSelected:(id)sender;
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Don't make `items` an array of strings, make it an array of custom objects that contain both the string you want to display and a `BOOL` member variable that remembers whether it is selected or not.

2) Only set your image during the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, not in other methods, and do it differently depending on the state of the `BOOL` variable mentioned above.

3) When the selected state changes due to your action method (or whatever) it should only change the `BOOL` state variable and then tell the table view to reload its data (which will trigger `cellForRowAtIndexPath`).

Comment: I have finally implemented this and it works, thank you! (I cannot vote up)